# Performing 3D colocalization & distance measuring with SimpleITK

Tags: python, numpy, simpleitk

I have some fairly large (~150MB) 3 channel 3D images I'm trying to process using python-simpleitk. I need to determine if objects in the red channel overlap with objects in the green channel and determine their distance from an object in the blue channel.

I haven't found anything about colocalization in the simpleitk documentation so I've been trying this using numpy to extract coordinates and determining how many voxels overlap. I haven't found any particular method for edge-to-edge distance measuring anywhere yet.

However, as expected, the numpy version takes quite a while and I'd rather use simpleitk for this (I've also looked into regular itk, but it causes problems converting to ndarrays).

I'm wondering if anyone has had any luck performing this type of image processing using these tools. Or can recommend improvements.

Here is my code so far.

```py
class ChannelImage(object):

    def __init__(self, image:np.ndarray, metadata:dict):
        self.object_map = None
        self.image = sitk.GetImageFromArray(image)
        self.metadata = metadata
        self.channel_ID = metadata['Color']
        # threshold hardcoded for now.
        if self.channel_ID == "Blue":
            self.threshold = 20000
        else:
            self.threshold = 10000
        del self.metadata['ID']
        del self.metadata['Color']

    def get_coords(self):
        cc = sitk.ConnectedComponent(self.image>self.threshold)
        self.object_map = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(cc)
        stats = sitk.LabelIntensityStatisticsImageFilter()
        stats.Execute(cc, self.image)
        labels = stats.GetLabels()
        print(f"Getting coordinates for {self.channel_ID}")
        self.coords = {label:np.where(self.object_map==label) for label in labels}
```

Answer (score 1):

SimpleITK does not currently have a method to directly get the coordinates of a label. I would recommend opening a feature request for SimpleITK.

In the mean time you can improve the efficiency of `np.where` by cropping the ndarray based on the `sitk.LabelIntensityStatisticsImageFilter.GetBoundingBox()` method.